# Partial derivative of a definite integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I'm creating this algorithm (kinda machine learning) and i have a function which is defined like this:
$$ V(x, y) = \int_a^b g(x,y,t) dt  $$
(a and b are some constants)
And then i want to calculate partial derivative of V over x and y, by using chain rule:
$$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial g} \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} $$
And I'm asking how to calculate this derivative of V over g. It's probably real simple but I can't figure it out

Comment: Under mild regularity assumptions (see dominated convergence theorem) you can just move the derivative inside the integral... $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = \int_a^b \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (x,y,t) dt.$$

Comment: By mild assumption I mean  that $g(x,y,t)$ is a Lebesgue-integrable  function of $t$ for each $(x,y) \in D$, that $g'_x$ exists for every $(x,y) \in D$ and almost every $t \in[a,b]$ and that exists an integrable function $|F(t)|$ such that $|f(x,y,t)|\leq |F(t)|$ for every $(x,y)\in D$ and almost every $t\in[a,b]$.

Comment: Also, $V$ is not a function of $g,$ or is it? (Note, you can definitely take the derivative with respect to a function if the appropriate Frechet spaces have been put on the table.)